# C# Hackerrank Duplicated Products

Tags: c#

First off, yes I am a 'noob' regarding C# anyway. I am an AS/400 programmer looking to learn .NET\C#. This is one of those blasted hackerrank questions called 'duplicated products'. My question is:

1. What is "OUTPUT_PATH" is supposed to be replaced with? I keep receiving the error 'Value cannot be null.(Parameter 'path')
2. Can you get this to compile and run successfully in Visual Studio on your computer and if so can you please indicate how?

I have researched this for literal hours but have yet to find someone who can answer this clearly or at all. There is usually just some hurling of insults....i.e., 'noob...this is one of those 'hackerrank' questions...' etc., as replies.

Thanks.

```
class Result
{

    /*
     * Complete the 'numDuplicates' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts following parameters:
     *  1. STRING_ARRAY name
     *  2. INTEGER_ARRAY price
     *  3. INTEGER_ARRAY weight
     */

    public static int numDuplicates(List<string> name, List<int> price, List<int> weight)
    {
        ISet<string> uniqueProducts = new HashSet<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Count; i++)
        {
            uniqueProducts.Add(name[i] + " " + price[i] + " " + weight[i]);
        }
        return name.Count - uniqueProducts.Count;  // Editor JT added this hint, to detect numDuplicates it should be - uniqueProducts.Distinct();
    }
}

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true); 
        
        int nameCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());


        List<string> name = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++)
        {
            string nameItem = Console.ReadLine();
            name.Add(nameItem);
        }

        int priceCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        List<int> price = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < priceCount; i++)
        {
            int priceItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
            price.Add(priceItem);
        }

        int weightCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        List<int> weight = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < weightCount; i++)
        {
            int weightItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
            weight.Add(weightItem);
        }

        int result = Result.numDuplicates(name, price, weight);

        textWriter.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: OUTPUT_PATH is an environment variable, you can set it in VS project debug settings

Comment: A `StreamWriter` should flush and close when disposed. If you `using TextWriter textWriter = ...`, then the compiler will ensure the file is closed when leaving the method's scope. (Though I think this is a template provided by hackerrank?)

Comment: Duplicate means the products with same name, weight and price?

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as Solution.cs
You can compile the file from command prompt with csc Solution.cs and run with Solution.exe inside the visual studio powershell.

```
//Add following required namespaces
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Result
{

    /*
     * Complete the 'numDuplicates' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts following parameters:
     *  1. STRING_ARRAY name
     *  2. INTEGER_ARRAY price
     *  3. INTEGER_ARRAY weight
     */

    public static int numDuplicates(List<string> name, List<int> price, List<int> weight)
    {
        ISet<string> uniqueProducts = new HashSet<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Count; i++)
        {
            uniqueProducts.Add(name[i] + " " + price[i] + " " + weight[i]);
        }
        return name.Count - uniqueProducts.Count;  // Editor JT added this hint, to detect numDuplicates it should be - uniqueProducts.Distinct();
    }
}

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create a folder "temp" under c: drive and add the following line
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH","c:\\temp\\Output.txt");
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many names you want to enter. e.g 3 ");
        int nameCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());


        List<string> name = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name " + (i + 1));
            string nameItem = Console.ReadLine();
            name.Add(nameItem);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many prices you want to enter. e.g 3 ");
        int priceCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        List<int> price = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < priceCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter price " + (i + 1));
            int priceItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
            price.Add(priceItem);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many weighs you want to enter. e.g 3 ");
        int weightCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        List<int> weight = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < weightCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter weight " + (i + 1));
            int weightItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
            weight.Add(weightItem);
        }

        int result = Result.numDuplicates(name, price, weight);

        textWriter.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```